# How to compare a field value with a number in an email template

Tags: netsuite, freemarker

I need to be able to show a line of text if the total value of an invoice is less than 5,000. I tried the below code but am getting an error:

```
<#if transaction.total &lt; 5000>Total is less than 5K</#if>
```

The error I am getting is the following:

> Can't compare values of these types. Allowed comparisons are between
> two numbers, two strings, two dates, or two booleans.Left hand operand is a hash+string(wrapper: com.netledger.model.StringModel)..Right hand operand is a number (weapper:f.t.SimpleNumber)..The blamed expression: ==> transaction.otal < 1000 [in template "content" at line 14, column 6]..----,FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related): Failed at: #if transaction.total %lt; 1000

How can I fix this?

Edited to add complete error message.

Comment: You aren't sharing the whole error message here. So I can only guess what the type of the left side is. Is it a string maybe? Then, if you can't fix the data model, parse it with `?number`.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates the code you show is not the code that is running:

From the error the template has `transaction.otal` not `transaction.total`

Comment: That was a typo on my part when copying over the error message.

Answer (score 0):

that's odd. I've looked through my templates and realized I've never compared any transaction currency fields. They do work as numbers though so you probably just need to coerce them a little. Note you don't need to escape a less than sign

try:

```
<#if (0+transaction.total) < 5000>Total is less than 5K</#if>
```

or

```
<#if transaction.total?number < 5000>Total is less than 5K</#if>
```